# Testing JavaScript Written for the Browser in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I have some JavaScript that is going to run in the browser, but I have broken the logic based functions that have nothing to do with the DOM into their own js files.

If it's possible, I would prefer to test these files via command line, why have to open a browser just to test code logic? After digging through multiple testing libraries for Node.js. I suppose it's not a big deal, but that seems to require that I build a whole node project, which requires that I provide a main, which doesn't really exist in my project since it's just functions that get fired from a web page.

Is there a solution for testing JavaScript functions that can be as simple as just writing a .js file with tests in it and calling a utility to run those tests? Something more simple than having to set up a runner, or build a project and manage dependencies? Something that feels like writing and running JUnit Tests in Eclipse, and a little less like having to set up a Maven project just to run MVN test?

As a follow-up question, is this even the right way to go about it? Is it normal to be running tests for JavaScript that is meant to run in the browser in Node.js?

Comment: `node filename.js`

Comment: I had thought this, but it is my understanding that this only works for a standalone file, right? So if I want to test function bar in foo.js, I can't do a var foo = require('./foo.js') in a test_foo.js file. Right?

Comment: you can, you just need to run that command and provide the name of the entry point of your code

Comment: that command is the standard way to start node.js applications

Comment: Ok, so using the test_foo example above. I have foo.js with function bar. in a test directory in the same directory as foo.js, I have test_foo.js. In test_foo.js I have "var foo = require('../foo.js')". Now when foo.bar is called, I get "TypeError: foo.bar is not a function"

Comment: have you exported anything from foo.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use test runners like mocha or jasmine. Very easy to setup and start writing test code. In mocha for example, you can write simple test cases like

```
var assert = require('assert');
var helper = require('../src/scripts/modules/helper.js');
var model = require('../src/scripts/modules/model.js');

model.first.setMenuItem ({
  'title': 'Veggie Burger',
  'count': 257,
  'id': 1
});

describe('increment', function(){
  console.log ("Count : " + model.first.getMenuItem().count);

  it('should increment the menu item', function(){
    helper.increment();
    assert.equal(model.first.getMenuItem().count, 258);
  });

});
```

and run them like

```
$ ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/*.js
```

where test/*.js are the specifications file (unit test file like the one above)

the output will be something like:

```
Count : 257


  increment
    ✓ should increment the menu item


  1 passing (5ms)
```

You can even use headless browser like PhantomJS to test containing DOM manipulation code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to accept [Ari Singh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800078/2779631) answer for recommending Mocha, and special kudos to [Ayush Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6021597/ayush-gupta) for leading me down a road that eventually let me write my js files in a format that could be ran in the browser and node.js.

Just to expand on Ari's answer a bit on some things that made life a little easier.

1. I installed mocha globally using `npm install -g mocha`. Additionally, I created a `test` directory that I put all my test in. By doing this, all I had to do to run my unit tests was call `mocha test`. No package.json, no lengthy paths into node_modules to run mocha.
2. Node js requires you to export the functions in one file that you want to use in another file, which JavaScript in browsers does not. In order to support both Node.js and JavaScript, I did the following:

In my root directory, I have `foo.js` with the following contents:

```
function bar() {
    console.log("Hi")
}

module.export = bar
```

Then in the `test` directory I have `test_foo.js` with the following contents (Note this example doesn't have a test, see Ari's answer for an example of writing tests in Mocha):

```
var bar = require('../foo.js')

bar()
```

Using this approach, I can test the bar function in node using `mocha test` and still use it in my HTML page by importing it as a script.